# CSS3 Keyframe transition alternate onclick issue

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

See jsfiddle here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sRE8/)

I'm trying to get the "Click Me" button to slide up on the 2nd click.  First click slides the box down, second slides it up. Any ideas why this isn't working as is?

```
<div id="slider" class="slide">test</div>

.slide {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#ddd;
  display:none;
  -webkit-animation:cssSlideDown 1s ease 0 alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssSlideDown {
  0%   {height:0px;}
  100% {height:100px;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be better off using *transitions* in this case.

```
height: 0;
transition: height 1s ease;
overflow: hidden;
```

Then in the JS

```
if(!e.style.height || e.style.height == '0px') {
    console.log('foo');
    e.style.height = '100px';
}
else {
    e.style.height = '0';
}
```

Since you seem to be using jQuery you can use `.css` instead which will save you quite a bit of code.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/9sRE8/2/